# Clearing the "Group by" drop down on the Application Insights portal

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I have a new Windows Application that I am adding Application Insights to. Adding a new chart gives the ability to Group on specific custom properties using a drop down. This drop down has 65 properties that AI must have added at some point. There were not specifically added.
We have a main AppInsights that takes all events. We've also created a AppInsight for development. The list of custom properties in the drop down is different between these two, even though the source code is the same.
It makes me suspect that there is some process that creates the drop down contents based on the incoming data.
The problem here is that the code has changed, and some properties are no longer available. We want to eliminate these values from the drop down, and add the new ones.
I am perfectly happy just deleting the entire list. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The items that are available in the group by are properties that have ever been received by the back end in data you've sent, and aren't editable.

for custom properties/metrics, there's a limit on how many properties the backend will allow before it stops collecting new named custom properties.   Conceptually, think of it as the backend storing an array of 200 elements for each telemetry item you sent, and mapping each custom property name to an index, and that mapping lasts forever. *(i believe at the current time that limit is 200 each, but we're working on expanding that)*

so if developers did things in your dev portal, even sent one item with custom property "foo", then that property will be there **forever**, and takes up one of those 200 slots.  They can't be deleted or cleared at the moment.

*Also*, the contents of the group by box is also limited to events that have sent less than some threshold of distinct values, too. *(I'm not sure on that exact value, but i believe it < 100 distinct values.)*  So fields like Id fields, or guids, etc, will eventually stop showing up as group by options, because the group by would create N distinct buckets of 1 item.

It seems like this would be something already mentioned in the [App Insights UserVoice site](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/category/77108-application-insights), or documented in the [azure documentation for group by](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-metrics-explorer/#segment-your-data) but i'm not seeing it.

The only real workaround at this time is to create a new application insights resource in azure, and start submitting data to that new resource instead of your old one.  And then you have to be proactive about never submitting custom properties that you're never going to use, or mixing case, as "Property1" and "property1" will be distinct properties...

If this is a big issue for you, i'd suggest submitting it to microsoft connect as a bug, or entering a uservoice suggestion above.  I'll pass this on as something that really needs to be documented in the group by thing in the azure docs, too.

Comment: Excellent response. I'd thought about creating a new AppInsight resource but thought there should be a better way. Also, thank you for the link.

Comment: no problem.  i've forwarded this on to the people who own these things, i know it is something we're working on, since even we've run into this ourselves.